# Architecture for monitoring system state within microservices

Tags: graph, microservices

I'm trying to build a service, which will monitor the current system state in graph structure. For example, if userA is subscribed on userB and have a chat with it, the graph should contain next relations:

A --subscribed on --> B

A --in chat with --> B

B --in chat with --> A

If userA exit chat, then the relation should be deleted.

Also, new microservices should be introduced, so no hardcoded decision (like to support subset of relations) cant be implemented.

Main problems are consistency of data and new relations which cannot be hardcoded.

I wonder if there are any solutions, or libraries, which can help me with this problem. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to store relationships as graphs or communicate between micro services?

Comment: I have bunch of microservices (chat, userservice, filestorage and more) and each of this has some relations in them (user is subscribed on other user, user is in category, etc). I have a task to build a common graph, representing all entities in all microservices and relations between them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your system should support an event driven architecture. For example any action that is potentially relevant to other parts of the system should be logged in an event queue. So now whenever your graph service is ready to update, it can read the event queue to the end and update its own state. This would be a solution that is decoupled as much as possible and resilient to data loss or other potential issues.

Typically people use a technology like Apache Kafka to realize a simple, lightweight, fast event queue for such purposes. It allows you to define queues, called topics, and consumers that process the topics. See [the docs](https://kafka.apache.org/).

Comment: Thank you. CQRS and Event Sourcing were the perfect solution.